# React , Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {data})

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I tried to pass a number as argument to function inside JSX the above error occured.

Working file Link : https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-hill-v3gl3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/new.js

React Component.

```
function Rating(data) {
  // This function indent to display number 0 to 3 based on 'data'; 
  switch (data) {
    case data <= 0: {
      return <div>0</div>;
    }
    case 0 < data <= 1: {
      return <div>1</div>;
    }
    case 1 < data <= 2: {
      return <div>2</div>;
    }
    case 2 < data <= 3: {
      return <div>3</div>;
    }
    default:
      return data;
  }
}

function some() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Rating data={product.totalrating} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default some;
```

Comment: The example you provided works. Can this question be marked as resolved?

Comment: Thanks, can you please provide me the code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the prop object instead the actual data:

```
// not Rating(data), 
// as the argument of function component is a prop object
function Rating({data}) {
  //...
  return data;
}
```

Comment: Thank you , please note that there is error in switch function, it returns default value instead of comparison. https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-hill-v3gl3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/new.js

Comment: Your switch statement is wrong, I pretty sure you can't use boolean expression there.

Comment: Oh I see,I did't know that

Comment: @AnoopKGeorge https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: Shall I use if else to compare boolean instead of switch

Comment: Yes you should.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you get is here:

```
function Rating(data) {
```

In a component you are receiving PROPS so you are getting an object like this:

```
data: {
 data: 1
}
```

In your code you are comparing with the object so you get the default case in the switch, returning the object above.

to fix it you can do:

```
function Rating({data}) {
```

or

```
function Rating(props) {
```

and use props.data for your comparations.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass props to the component, you receive them as object.
If you pass

```
<Rating data={data} />
```

then you receive props in a Rating component like { data: YOUR DATA }

Link to working sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-smoke-wl8he